# Are there any possible applications of real-time Finite Element Analysis?

Tags: finite-element

FEA when applied to solid mechanics / structural engineering result in the solution to the equation 
$$ F = K\cdot x $$
$F$ being the forces, $K$ the stiffness of the system and $x$ represents the resulting displacement.

Now if I were to analyse a live experiment where, lets say, I am applying a point load to a beam, gradually increasing in magnitude. As the load increases the deflection in the beam increases.

Using some sensors and data-acquisition system, if I were to read this load, into a FE program, then I would have, in the equation above, a scenario of load  which updates, every few seconds, and this should result in new solution to the FE equation. Also, the actual displacement values can be read using a displacement sensor and fed to the FE program for validation / model updation.

This creates kind of a loop, and completes the definition of real-time FE solver.

Would such a system have any practical use?

Comment: Some applications have been in the field of surgery. E.g., http://www.amses-journal.com/content/pdf/2213-7467-1-11.pdf

Comment: I seem to recall a guest lecture discussing wind farm blade control systems ... I will see if I can find the reference,

Answer (score 4):

There are hundreds of reasons you might want to do this. Any real-time control system can use an accurate model of the system being controlled to improve the predictor part of the controller. Weather forecasts need to run faster than real time to be useful. I don't know of anyone doing weather with FEM off the top of my head, but you easily could. Etc. Etc.

Comment: Yes, there are FEM Numerical Weather Predicition (NWP) models, e.g. US Navy's [NUMA](http://www.icms.org.uk/downloads/Galerkin/Giraldo.pdf).  I'm unsure if any are operational yet.

Comment: This would also have application in video game and visual effects. For games, real-time accurate FEA can provide for a more immersive game experience as compared to all the indestructible models used today. For visual effects, it can provide the artist the ability to iterate on their effect much more quickly than today, saving time/cost and hopefully a better end product, given that more iterations could be examined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you describe is more-or-less how some tanks are able to fire while moving.  They have a differential model of the turret, sensors and actuators.